# Rails: carrierwave file name updating on every updates with model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm trying to write new file name on uploaded file with `carrierwave` and I have used two methods on `app/uploaders/media_uploader.rb`

```
def filename
    "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}"
end

protected
def secure_token
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
end

#model/user.rb
mount_uploader :avatar, MediaUploader
```

This working perfectly when uploading new or update file, but the problem is when I work with other attributes like updating my `name`, `email`, or `bio` using a different form then file name updating continuously then file are missing after update other attributes.

What can I do now?

Comment: I believe the problem is that you need to sanitize `name`, `email` and  `bio`. I would look into the carrierwave source code, especially into the class your `media_uploader.rb` is inheriting from

Comment: also I don't think using set or get inside a single method is a good idea. hard to debug this without knowing where `mounted_as` is defined.

Comment: Ok, I will update my question while available in the desk. @FabrizioBertoglio

Answer (score 0):

You can resave it by calling `file.cache_stored_file!`, I found this [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Recreate-and-reprocess-your-files-stored-on-fog). I had my uploader path depending on `updated_at` so I did the following in my model:

My Uploader

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}/#{model.updated_at.to_i}"
end
```

My Model

```
before_update :update_file_path
...
def update_file_path
  my_uploader.cache_stored_file! if changed?
end
```